# Arquillian with weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, weblogic, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to test war (having EJB) on Weblogic using Arquillian.

My setup:

- gradle 2.12
- `build.gradle` has:

  ```
  dependencies {
      providedCompile 'javax.ejb:ejb-api:3.0'

      compile "org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:2.6.2"

      testCompile "org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-wls-remote-10.3.x:1.0.1.Final"   
      testCompile "org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-gradle-depchain:2.2.2"   
      testCompile "org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:1.1.11.Final"
      testCompile "org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:1.1.11.Final"


      testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
  }
  ```
- test class holds:

  ```
  @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
  public class FooTest {


  @Deployment
      public static EnterpriseArchive deploy() {
           WebArchive webArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(EmbeddedGradleImporter.class) //
          .forThisProjectDirectory() //
          .importBuildOutput() //
          .as(WebArchive.class) //
          .addPackages(true, "foo") //
          .addClass(FooTest.class)
          ;

            EnterpriseArchive enterpriseArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class, "foo.ear") //
              .addAsModule(webArchive) //             
              ;


            return enterpriseArchive;
          }

      @Test
      public void test() throws Exception {
          // TODO
          assertNotNull(null);
      }
  ...
  ```

However once deployment succeeds + test is supposed to start, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getTestClass()Lorg/junit/runners/model/TestClass; from class org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:202)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:426)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:218)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:166)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:66)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:170)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

As far as I understood, the problem is with some old version of JUnit (4.8.1) is required, due to interface incompatibilities. However I'm having later version than that.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Could it be that WLS has older JUnit in the classpath somehow? I cannot really bet on anything else as this exact combination of ARQ and JUnit works in all my projects (except that we are not using WLS).

Comment: Can you share your `arquillian.xml` config? You can configure it in a way that the final deployment with all the libraries is exported to some arbitrary folder so you can inspect what lands in your container - here's an example https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-persistence/blob/master/int-tests/src/test/resources-glassfish-3.1-derby/arquillian.xml#L8